# How to print specific column from CSV, excluding the first row - Python 3.x

Tags: python, google-maps, average

Python 3.x

I have a program collecting data from Google Maps API, for a specific route. This is being saved as a CSV file. (https://github.com/mcole22266/traffic_data)

I am looking to average all the journey times, and then compare the most recent journey time to the average.

I am only able to print all the values (i.e. the timestamp, start address and )in the last row, when using the method shown below.

`with open(path) as f1:
      last_line = f1.readlines()[-1]
      print(last_line)`

Comment: You probably need `f1.readlines()[1:]`. This will ensure that you skip only the first row and take all others.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Pandas** library to read `csv` file, `print` specific columns and `exclude` first row.

To read a csv file,

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

To read a csv file while excluding first row,

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', skiprows = 1)
```

To read a csv file while excluding header row,

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv', skiprows = 1, header = None)
```

`filename` is any name of csv file.

To print specific columns of csv file after reading,

```
df[cols_list]
```

Here, `cols_list` is the list of column names you want to print